# 2D filled.contour plot with 1D histograms by axes by R

Tags: histogram

I hope this question is beyond "read the manual". My task is simple, just to plot the following, but the plot in the middle should be a filled.contour plot:
http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Scatterplot_with_marginal_histograms_78

Background: I prefer filled.contour rather than hist2d. Because, I could use kernel smooth, so the plot for discrete data won't be too ugly. I also tried image() and then contour(), but the number on contour is not clear and no indication about the color.

My problem: in filled.contour function, it uses layout() for filledcontour() plot and rect() plot (color bar). However, I use layout() in the outside code to organize 2 histogram and one filled.contour plot. Looks like, the layout outside is shadowed by filled.contour(). I am not sure how R deal with this problem. Should I rewrite filled.contour() somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help page ?filled.contour you will see that it also mentions another function called `.filled.contour` (extra `.` at the front) which does just the bare bones plotting without calling `layout` and causing the problems that you see.  You need to do more of the checking and prelim work, but you should be able to do what you want using `.filled.contour` for the main plot and setting up the layout yourself.